# Discrete approximation - exponential function and integrals

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, approximation

Let $f$ be a complex-valued continuous function on $\mathbb{R}_+$ with compact support and let $g, h$ be two  complex-valued continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}_+$ such that $g$ is bounded and $|h(t)|$=1.
Let $0 \leq s < t < \infty$.

Find a limit as $n \to \infty$ of

$\prod \limits_{j=k+1}^{r} \left[ \sqrt{1- \frac{1}{n}| g(\frac{j}{n})|^2}+f(\frac{j}{n})h(\frac{j}{n})\sqrt{1- \frac{1}{n}| g(\frac{j}{n})|^2}\right] \times \prod \limits_{j\notin \{k+1, \ldots, r \}}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{j}{n})\right) $

where $\frac{k}{n}< s \leq \frac{k+1}{n} \leq \frac{r}{n} \leq t < \frac{r+1}{n}$.

It should be of the form
$\exp\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx + \int_{s}^{t} \left(-\frac{1}{2}|g(x)|^2  + f(x)(h(x)-1)\right) dx\right]$.

Hints are mean value theorems and Plancherel theorem, but I have no idea how to apply it.

Thank you for any hints and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a $\frac1n$ missing before the term $f(\frac{j}{n})h(\frac{j}{n})$.

Taking  logarithms turns this product into a Riemann sum plus some terms which are negligible in the limit.  For example, observe that, since $f$ has compact support, we can assume that $f(x)$ vanishes for $x> L$, for some fixed $L>t$.  Then the product over $j\notin\{k+1,\ldots,r\}$ can be cut off at $Ln$,  so
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\log \prod_{j\notin\{k+1,\ldots,r\}} (1+\frac1n f(\frac jn))\\
&=&\sum_{j\notin\{k+1,\ldots,r\},\ j\le Ln} \log (1+\frac1n f(\frac jn))\\
&=&\sum_{j\notin\{k+1,\ldots,r\},\ j\le Ln} (\frac1n f(\frac jn) + O(\frac{1}{n^2})),\\
\end{eqnarray*}
where, since $|f|$ is bounded on ${\Bbb R}_+$, the $O()$ term is uniform in $j$
$$
=O(\frac1n) + \sum_{j\notin\{k+1,\ldots,r\},\ j\le Ln} \frac1n f(\frac jn).
$$
The first term vanishes in the limit and the second is a Riemann sum whose limit is $$\int_0^s f(x) \, dx+\int_t^L f(x) \, dx.$$

The term in the other part of the product,
$$ \sqrt{1- \frac{1}{n}| g(\frac{j}{n})|^2}+\frac1nf(\frac{j}{n})h(\frac{j}{n})\sqrt{1- \frac{1}{n}| g(\frac{j}{n})|^2},$$
factors as
$$ \sqrt{1- \frac{1}{n}| g(\frac{j}{n})|^2}\left(1+\frac1nf(\frac{j}{n})h(\frac{j}{n})\right).$$
You can then deal with in it the same way, giving a logarithmic limit of
$$
\int_s^t -\frac12 |g(x)|^2 + f(x)h(x) \, dx.
$$
Adding and exponentiating then gives the desired result.

Re the comments below, suppose that you replaced the term in the first product by
$$ T_{jn}:=\sqrt{1- \frac{1}{n}| g(\frac{j}{n})|^2}+\frac1n \left(h(\frac{j}{n})+f(\frac{j}{n})h(\frac{j}{n})\sqrt{1- \frac{1}{n}| g(\frac{j}{n})|^2}\right).\ \ (1)$$
Then, use the Taylor expansion
$$
\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n} |g(\frac{j}{n})|^2}=1-\frac{1}{2n} |g(\frac{j}{n})|^2+O(\frac{1}{n^2}).\qquad (2)
$$
Since $g$ is bounded, the $O()$ term is uniform in $j$.  Therefore, substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$,
$$
T_{jn}=1-\frac{1}{2n} |g(\frac{j}{n})|^2+\frac1n h(\frac jn) + \frac1n f(\frac jn) h(\frac jn) + O(\frac{1}{n^2}),
$$
and so
$$
\log T_{jn}=-\frac{1}{2n} |g(\frac{j}{n})|^2+\frac1n h(\frac jn) + \frac1n f(\frac jn) h(\frac jn) +O(\frac{1}{n^2}).\qquad (3)
$$
Since $f$, $g$ and $h$ are all bounded on the interval being considered, the $O()$ term is still uniform in $j$ in both of these expressions.
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\log \prod_{k+1\le j\le r} T_{jn}\\
&=&\sum_{k+1\le j\le r} \log T_{jn}\\
&=&O(\frac 1n)+\sum_{k+1\le j\le r} -\frac{1}{2n} |g(\frac{j}{n})|^2+\frac1n h(\frac jn) + \frac1n f(\frac jn) h(\frac jn),\\
\end{eqnarray*}
using $(3)$, and as before the sum on the right-hand side is a Riemann sum.

Comment: What if there will be an extra term like  $\prod \limits_{j=k+1}^{r} \left[ \sqrt{1- \frac{1}{n}| g(\frac{j}{n})|^2}+\frac{1}{n}\left(h(\frac{j}{n})+f(\frac{j}{n})h(\frac{j}{n}) \sqrt{1- \frac{1}{n}| g(\frac{j}{n})|^2}\right)\right]$ ? Is there any way to decompose it nicely?

Comment: It still works out in the same way.  The extra term gives an extra $\int h(x) \, dx$ in the logarithmic limit.

Comment: I can't see how, in the first situation due to the logarithm properties $\ln \left[\left(\sqrt{1- \frac{1}{n}|g(\frac{j}{n})|^2} \right)\left(1+ f(\frac{j}{n})h(\frac{j}{n})\right)\right]= \frac{1}{2}\ln \left( 1- \frac{1}{n}|g(\frac{j}{n})|^2 \right)+ \ln\left( 1+ f(\frac{j}{n})h(\frac{j}{n})\right)$ and now we can use the trick with Taylor expansion. If there is an extra term $h(\frac{j}{n})$ we cannot factorize it in a nice way.

Comment: It's nicer to factorize the term you're taking the product of, but it's not necessary.  You can write it as $1+(1/n) \Phi(j/n) +O(1/n^2)$ for some function $\Phi$.  Then take logarithms.

Comment: Are we also expanding the square root to get that $1$ ? Is it the solution?

Comment: I added a working of this case in the main body of the answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was really silly. I just realize that we can also expand the square root there. Thanks a lot!